# Should I save user notification in database or json file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Im desining a control like `Facebook notification` via SignalR. But I have a problem: when a user gets new notification, where should I save it?

These are my suggestions:

1/. Save to database.

```
[Table("Notifications")]
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this solution is: if my website has more than 200 users and all of them have 10 new notifications at the same time, the controller will hit to database 2000 times at least. That's so awful.

2/. Save to json file:

```
[
    {
        UserId_1:
            NotiId: "",
            Message: "",
            IsRead: false,
            DateTime: ...
    },
    {
        UserId_2:
            NotiId: "",
            Message: "",
            IsRead: false,
            DateTime: ...
    }
]
```

The problem with this solution is: if my server has more than 200 users, the array length will be too long. It's so difficult to work (read already information and append new information). It also makes server goes slowly.

Any idea?

Comment: The only real option here is a database, you will just need to implement it well.

Comment: Is hitting a database 2000 times a problem? Surely any decent database will handle this without any trouble. I woun't worry about performance issues until you've profiled and then identified that there is in fact a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to save notifications in memory cache upto certain level, and then bulk save them in database.